# Can't echo tabel values when useing vararable

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to compaire 2 rows from my table called HK.  This is my code

```
<?php require_once('Connections/hk.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$month_1 = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['Month'])) {
    $month_1 = $_GET['Month'];
}

$year_1 = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['year'])) {
    $year_1 = $_GET['year'];
}

mysql_select_db($database_hk, $hk);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE 'Month' = '.$month_1' AND 'year' = $year_1";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $hk) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);


$month_2 = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['Month2'])) {
    $month_2 = $_GET['Month2'];
}

$year_2 = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['year2'])) {
    $year_2 = $_GET['year2'];
}


mysql_select_db($database_hk, $hk);
$query_Recordset2 = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE 'Month' = Month AND year = $year_2";
$Recordset2 = mysql_query($query_Recordset2, $hk) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset2);
$totalRows_Recordset2 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset2);

mysql_select_db($database_hk, $hk);
$query_Recordset3 = "SELECT * FROM inventory_month";
$Recordset3 = mysql_query($query_Recordset3, $hk) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset3);
$totalRows_Recordset3 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset3);
?>
```

When I try `<?php echo $row_Recordset1['Month']; ?> <?php echo $row_Recordset2['year']; ?>` I get nothing.  I also checked my var with `print_r($_GET);`
 and I get Array ( [Month1] => December [year1] => 2014 [Month2] => January [year2] => 2015 [submit] => View )

So if my var are set why will it not echo the month and year

Comment: Where did you find this code with the test `if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {`

Comment: @mark it's part of the dreamweaver template

Comment: Your SQL query has a mistake. You have `"SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE 'Month' = '.$month_1' AND 'year' = $year_1"` where it should be `"SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE 'Month' = '$month_1' AND 'year' = $year_1"` (Note the removed `.` in front of `$month_1`)

Comment: Your second SQL query also has a mistake with `'Month' = Month` where I think you meant `'Month' = '$month_2'`.

Comment: @turnerj the . Was just something I wad trying I tryed it first as you said but still did not work.  Should I be useing $_get or $_ POST The form is get with no action

Comment: Have you tried echoing out the actual SQL statement and running it separately (eg. via PHPMyAdmin) to make sure there are results returned?

Comment: @turnerj I'm still new to this what part of the code would I need to copy to the SQL tab in phpmyadmin

Comment: What you want to do is echo out the values for `$query_Recordset1` and `$query_Recordset2` which would be your SQL queries. You are wanting to check if any results are actually returned by the queries.

Comment: @turnerj So I did as you said and echoed the query and this is what I got

SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE 'Month' = -1 AND 'year' = -1
SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE 'Month' = -1 AND 'year' = 2014 

I have looked at and copyed over the $year_1 with $year_2 and changed the number.  I have no Idea $year_2 is showing 2014 but $year_1 is showing -1, also why both $month_1 and $month_2 are showing -1

Do you have any thought on this.

Comment: Your GET request has "Month1" and "year1" yet your PHP is looking for "Month" and "year", that's the first problem. I assume for the second query you did my update as I suggested in my previous comment about `'Month' = '$month_2'`.

Comment: What I recommend for you to do is more debugging of your own code. You now know that your query wasn't being set correctly and you know that your GET variables are being set as per your `print_r` call. It is a matter of working back, finding the problem and fixing. If I am looking at your code in a couple of seconds and pointing these things out, it makes me think you are not looking at your code thoroughly enough. I get that you might be newer to programming though debugging is absolutely crucial for being able to solve problems.

Comment: @Turnerj

Fix it
"SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE 'Month' = '$month_2' AND 'year' = $year_2";

But it is still not echoing the <?php echo $row_Recordset1['Month']; ?>

Comment: @Turnerj Thanks for all your help and not just telling me to google it.  It has been fixed.  here's is now. 
$query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE Month = %s AND year = $year_1", GetSQLValueString($month_1, "text"), GetSQLValueString($year_1, "text"));

Comment: No problem. Your particular question would have been a bit difficult to Google given the specific nature of it. It might be worth you answering your own question with both the fixed code and a few notes regarding your specific changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed

```
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE 'Month' = '.$month_1' AND 'year' = $year_1";
```

To

```
$query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE Month = %s AND year = $year_1", GetSQLValueString($month_1, "text"), GetSQLValueString($year_1, "text"));
```

and

```
$query_Recordset2 = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE 'Month' = Month AND year = $year_2";
```

TO

```
$query_Recordset2 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE Month = %s AND year = $year_2", GetSQLValueString($month_2, "text"), GetSQLValueString($year_2, "text"));
```